# How to have collapsed fields of a group on first load of page when rendered through rails_admin controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

I am using mongoid db. So, I group fields based on their relevance with each other. But I have too many field hence a lot many groups and during the **edit** action when the page load initially I want them to be collapsed but can't find a way to do it. Since the controller if from gem **rails_admin** I have no idea how to configure it, though as an hack I can use the class name generated by the rails_admin for group and trigger click on them but that hack also is difficult is accomplish. As I said controller is controlled by gem, so not an option to configure them. I browsed through all the listed issues of rails_admin on github, but of no avail. So someone please tell me how to do it.

**Edit**:
Elaboration of question:- Following snippet is in rails **Model**

```
rails_admin do
  # ..... some logic
  edit do
    group 'Sample Group-1' do
      label "Sample Group"
      field(:field_1) do
        label "Field-1"
      end
      field(:filed_2) do
        label "Field-2"
      end
      field(:field_3) do
        label "Field-3"
      end
      field(:field_4) do
        label "Field-4"
      end
      field(:field_s) do
        label "Field-5"
      end
    end
  end
end 
# ......
# some more groups
```

this produce following on edit page

[image]

But I would rather want like this when page loads initially:-
   [image]

Since I have a lot many groups and it becomes cumbersome for user to edit hence on initial load I want the groups to be collapsed. Someone help.

Any help will be appreciated. Google didn't help. Neither does the documentation.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it is pretty simple. just do it this way:

```
group 'Sample Group-1' do
  active false # this one is the key
  # ... rest of the code 
end
```

Cheers!!!